# Pandas and unicode

Tags: python, unicode, pandas

This is a string I'm getting out of `pandas.DataFrame.to_json()`, putting it into redis, getting it out of redis elsewhere, and trying to read it via `pandas.read_json()`:

```
DFJ {"args":{"0":"[]","1":"[]","2":"[]","3":"[]","4":"[]","5":"[]","6":"[]","7":"[]"},"date":{"0":1385944439000000000,"1":1385944439000000000,"2":1385944440000000000,"3":1385944440000000000,"4":1385944440000000000,"5":1385944440000000000,"6":1385944440000000000,"7":1385944440000000000},"host":{"0":"yy38.segm1.org","1":"kyy1.segm1.org","2":"yy10.segm1.org","3":"yy24.segm1.org","4":"yy24.segm1.org","5":"yy34.segm1.org","6":"yy15.segm1.org","7":"yy15.segm1.org"},"kwargs":{"0":"{}","1":"{}","2":"{}","3":"{}","4":"{}","5":"{}","6":"{}","7":"{}"},"operation":{"0":"x_gbinf","1":"x_initobj","2":"x_gobjParams","3":"gtfull","4":"x_gbinf","5":"gxyzinf","6":"deletemfg","7":"gxyzinf"},"thingy":{"0":"a13yy38","1":"a19kyy1","2":"a14yy10","3":"a14yy24","4":"a14yy24","5":"a12yy34","6":"a15yy15","7":"a15yy15"},"status":{"0":-101,"1":1,"2":-101,"3":-101,"4":-101,"5":-101,"6":1,"7":-101},"time":{"0":0.000801,"1":0.003244,"2":0.002247,"3":0.002787,"4":0.001067,"5":0.002652,"6":0.004371,"7":0.000602}}
```

It seems like it does not have any unicode in it. Yet on trying to `.read_json()` it I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sqlprofile.py", line 160, in <module>
    maybe_save_dataframes(rconn, configd, results)
  File "./sqlprofile.py", line 140, in maybe_save_dataframes
    h5store.append(out_queue, df)
  File "/home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 658, in append
    self._write_to_group(key, value, table=True, append=True, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 923, in _write_to_group
    s.write(obj = value, append=append, complib=complib, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 2985, in write
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 2717, in create_axes
    raise e
TypeError: [unicode] is not implemented as a table column
> /home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py(2717)create_axes()
-> raise e
(Pdb) locals()
```

This is what I'm getting in `locals()` - it seems that `append_axis` (column names?) values are unicode. Why?

```
{'append_axis': [u'args', u'date', u'host', u'kwargs', u'operation', u'thingy', u'status', u'time'], 'existing_table': None, 'blocks': [FloatBlock: [time], 1 x 8, dtype float64, ObjectBlock: [args, host, kwargs, operation, thingy], 5 x 8, dtype object, IntBlock: [status], 1 x 8, dtype int64, DatetimeBlock: [date], 1 x 8, dtype datetime64[ns]], 'axis': 1, 'self': frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->None,ncols->1,indexers->[index]), 'axes': [0], 'kwargs': {}, 'klass': <class 'pandas.io.pytables.DataCol'>, 'block_obj':   args                date            host kwargs              operation      thingy  status      time
0   [] 2013-12-02 00:33:59  yy38.segm1.org     {}       x_gbinf  a13yy38    -101  0.000801
1   [] 2013-12-02 00:33:59  kyy1.segm1.org     {}         x_initobj  a19kyy1       1  0.003244
2   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy10.segm1.org     {}    x_gobjParams  a14yy10    -101  0.002247
3   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy24.segm1.org     {}        gtfull  a14yy24    -101  0.002787
4   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy24.segm1.org     {}       x_gbinf  a14yy24    -101  0.001067
5   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy34.segm1.org     {}           gxyzinf  a12yy34    -101  0.002652
6   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy15.segm1.org     {}  deletemfg  a15yy15       1  0.004371
7   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy15.segm1.org     {}           gxyzinf  a15yy15    -101  0.000602, 'axis_labels': [u'args', u'date', u'host', u'kwargs', u'operation', u'thingy', u'status', u'time'], 'nan_rep': 'nan', 'data_columns': [], 'obj':   args                date            host kwargs              operation      thingy  status      time
0   [] 2013-12-02 00:33:59  yy38.segm1.org     {}       x_gbinf  a13yy38    -101  0.000801
1   [] 2013-12-02 00:33:59  kyy1.segm1.org     {}         x_initobj  a19kyy1       1  0.003244
2   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy10.segm1.org     {}    x_gobjParams  a14yy10    -101  0.002247
3   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy24.segm1.org     {}        gtfull  a14yy24    -101  0.002787
4   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy24.segm1.org     {}       x_gbinf  a14yy24    -101  0.001067
5   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy34.segm1.org     {}           gxyzinf  a12yy34    -101  0.002652
6   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy15.segm1.org     {}  deletemfg  a15yy15       1  0.004371
7   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy15.segm1.org     {}           gxyzinf  a15yy15    -101  0.000602, 'validate': True, 'a': (1, [u'args', u'date', u'host', u'kwargs', u'operation', u'thingy', u'status', u'time']), 'index_axes_map': {0: name->index,cname->index,axis->0,pos->0,kind->integer}, 'b': ObjectBlock: [args, host, kwargs, operation, thingy], 5 x 8, dtype object, 'e': TypeError('[unicode] is not implemented as a table column',), 'name': None, 'existing_col': None, 'j': 2, 'i': 1, 'min_itemsize': None, 'col': name->values_block_1,cname->values_block_1,dtype->None,shape->None}
```

How can I fix that? Is this a bug in Pandas / pytables?

Environment:

Python 2.7

pandas==0.12.0

tables==3.0.0

Comment: Without DFG at the beginning, read_json on the first string works fine for me in both 0.12 (and 0.13rc).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Seems your roundtripping IS causing some unicode. Not sure why that is, but easy to fix.
You cannot store unicode in a HDFStore Table in python 2, (this works correctly in python 3 however). You could do it as a Fixed format if you want though (it would be pickled). See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#fixed-format).

```
In [33]: df = pd.read_json(s)

In [25]: df
Out[25]: 
  args                date            host kwargs     operation  status   thingy      time
0   [] 2013-12-02 00:33:59  yy38.segm1.org     {}       x_gbinf    -101  a13yy38  0.000801
1   [] 2013-12-02 00:33:59  kyy1.segm1.org     {}     x_initobj       1  a19kyy1  0.003244
2   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy10.segm1.org     {}  x_gobjParams    -101  a14yy10  0.002247
3   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy24.segm1.org     {}        gtfull    -101  a14yy24  0.002787
4   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy24.segm1.org     {}       x_gbinf    -101  a14yy24  0.001067
5   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy34.segm1.org     {}       gxyzinf    -101  a12yy34  0.002652
6   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy15.segm1.org     {}     deletemfg       1  a15yy15  0.004371
7   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy15.segm1.org     {}       gxyzinf    -101  a15yy15  0.000602

[8 rows x 8 columns]

In [26]: df.dtypes
Out[26]: 
args                 object
date         datetime64[ns]
host                 object
kwargs               object
operation            object
status                int64
thingy               object
time                float64
dtype: object
```

This is inferring the actual type of the `object` dtyped Series. They will come out as unicode only if at least 1 string is unicode (otherwise they would be inferred as string)

```
In [27]: df.apply(lambda x: pd.lib.infer_dtype(x.values))
Out[27]: 
args            unicode
date         datetime64
host            unicode
kwargs          unicode
operation       unicode
status          integer
thingy          unicode
time           floating
dtype: object
```

Here's how to 'fix' it

```
In [28]: types = df.apply(lambda x: pd.lib.infer_dtype(x.values))

In [29]: types[types=='unicode']
Out[29]: 
args         unicode
host         unicode
kwargs       unicode
operation    unicode
thingy       unicode
dtype: object

In [30]: for col in types[types=='unicode'].index:
   ....:     df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
   ....:
```

Looks the same

```
In [31]: df
Out[31]: 
  args                date            host kwargs     operation  status   thingy      time
0   [] 2013-12-02 00:33:59  yy38.segm1.org     {}       x_gbinf    -101  a13yy38  0.000801
1   [] 2013-12-02 00:33:59  kyy1.segm1.org     {}     x_initobj       1  a19kyy1  0.003244
2   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy10.segm1.org     {}  x_gobjParams    -101  a14yy10  0.002247
3   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy24.segm1.org     {}        gtfull    -101  a14yy24  0.002787
4   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy24.segm1.org     {}       x_gbinf    -101  a14yy24  0.001067
5   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy34.segm1.org     {}       gxyzinf    -101  a12yy34  0.002652
6   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy15.segm1.org     {}     deletemfg       1  a15yy15  0.004371
7   [] 2013-12-02 00:34:00  yy15.segm1.org     {}       gxyzinf    -101  a15yy15  0.000602

[8 rows x 8 columns]
```

But now infers correctly.

```
In [32]: df.apply(lambda x: pd.lib.infer_dtype(x.values))
Out[32]: 
args             string
date         datetime64
host             string
kwargs           string
operation        string
status          integer
thingy           string
time           floating
dtype: object
```

Comment: THANK YOU! this works. Although this seems tb a strange omission, given python's JSON decoder logic: "json.loads(s) ...
Deserialize s (a str or unicode instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.". Conversion table: http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json-to-py-table . This means that even in P2.7 the only string-type objects that come out of JSON decoding is unicode.

Comment: this does not use the python json decode, rather a custom decoder based on ujson. Haven't seen this before.

Comment: I'm seeing this *only* after running map/reduce workers (shepherd/mincemeat). That is, I'm getting data out of redis after `shepherd.run_server()` finished running (in the main process). Using returned results (as keys), I'm getting dataframes out of redis as strings (put there by .to_json() in reduce workers) and then saving them to HDF5 - no subprocess, no m/r, just a plain Python function. What's truly weird is that if I do that in IPython "manually" the above exception does not happen.

Comment: ahh...do you happen to have an encoding / locale set somewhere?

Comment: maybe. I did not mess with it myself for sure, "just" source Anaconda's virtual env. Like this: `. ~/anaconda/bin/activate ~/anaconda`  .  (env: Debian 7.2, x64; Python 2.7.5 :: Anaconda 1.8.0 (64-bit))

Comment: in your env that is giving a problem, print out ``pd.get_optinon('display.encoding')``; should be he same as in ipython

Comment: you're a treasure! Ipython: `pd.get_option('display.encoding') Out[141]: 'UTF-8'`. Problem environment: `ANSI_X3.4-1968`. Yikes! Why is that happening? I have tried different options in shells everywhere (in the prob environment) that matters: `LC_ALL=C`, `LC_ALL=POSIX`, UTF-8 too and it still happens.

Comment: I think tht is the default on some systems IIRC. I think you could just set this s soon as you import python. its in ``sys`` somewhere (you cn just set with pandas too, via ``set_option(...)`` that might fix it for you

Comment: Using `df[col] = df[col].astype(str)` will convert `None` or `np.NaN` values to the string representation (e.g. `'None'` and `'np.NaN'` respectively)

Comment: In recent versions of pandas, this solution yields: 
FutureWarning: pandas.lib is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. You can access infer_dtype as pandas.api.types.infer_dtype

Replace:
df.apply(lambda x: pd.lib.infer_dtype(x.values))
with:
df.apply(lambda x: pd.api.types.infer_dtype(x.values))

Answer (score 8):

The above solution may cause some errors with unicode special characters. A similar solution to convert unicode to string that will not get hung up on unicode special characters:

```
for col in types[types=='unicode'].index:
     df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8').strip())
```

This is due in part to how python handles unicode. More info on that in the Python [Unicode How-To](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html).