# Pandas, convert column of unicodes to column of list of strings

Tags: python, string, unicode, pandas, type-conversion

One of my pandas dataframe columns has unicodes of this kind `u'asd,abc,tre,der34,whatever'`. The final results should be a column of lists of strings: `['asd','abc','tre','der34','whatever']`. A list of unicodes might do, too: `[u'asd',u'abc',u'tre',u'der34',u'whatever']`.

By the way, tt can happen that in the column of unicodes there is a nan or a u''.

Any suggestion? I know I can do `str(df['column'].iloc[0]).split(',')` and manually add a new column or do something trickier, but I was looking for something more pythonic.

Comment: You have a mix of unicode and non unicode? What's the issue? Does this help `df['Column'] = df['Column'].astype(str)`?

Comment: I have a column of only unicodes, basically. But yes, your answers helps. I solve like this `df['Column'] =df['Column'].astype(str).str.split(',')` Thank you :)

Comment: You should post as an answer, also how has this happened, it's a bit weird to have a mix of encodings.

Comment: The unicode columns comes from a SQL text column. Why you say that there is a mix of encodings?

Comment: Because of this in your post `u'asd,abc,tre,der34,whatever'` I think I thought this was a list of strings rather than a string of a list of strings. Ignore my comment, anyway glad I helped

Comment: See the question, [Pandas and unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670370/pandas-and-unicode), for a more pythonic answer.

Answer (score 3):

This solution seems to work:

```
df['Column'] =df['Column'].astype(str).str.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if there were nan or empty string you'd have to handle that however you see fit.

```
In [1]: [str(col) for col in u'asd,abc,tre,der34,whatever'.split(',')]

Out[1]: ['asd', 'abc', 'tre', 'der34', 'whatever']
```