# pandas DF from numpy structured array: can't get unicode or string type for column (only object)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I pull data out of a software system, which gives me a numpy structured array. I convert this to a pandas DataFrame to do work and then need to convert it back to a structured array so I can push it back into the original system. String/text data shows up in the array as a unicode column and gets described as an object in the DF. Been trying to figure out how to get it back to either unicode or string, either in the DF or even the ending array, but having trouble. In the interest of asking a single question, how do I get a DF column dtype to be unicode/string?

Here's what I'm trying, the column 'region' is the one I'm focusing on:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arr = array([(1, u'01', 7733855, 0), (2, u'01', 7733919, 1244),
       (3, u'01', 7732571, 1236), (4, u'01', 7732387, 1234),
       (5, u'01', 7733327, 1239), (6, u'01', 7733755, 1241),
       (7, u'01', 7732571, 1236), (8, u'01', 7733923, 0),
       (9, u'01', 7733327, 1239), (10, u'01', 7733755, 1241)], 
      dtype=[('hru_id_nat', '<i4'), ('region', '<U255'), ('POI_ID', '<i4'), ('hru_segment', '<i4')])
```

Then I can make into a DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df.dtypes
```

shows that 'region' has an `object` dtype:

```
hru_id_nat      int32
region         object
POI_ID          int32
hru_segment     int32
dtype: object
```

I try to specify the dtypes when converting to DF, but not quite getting it:

```
n = list(arr.dtype.names)
t = [i[0].name for i in arr.dtype.fields.values()]
dt = [(i, j) for i, j in zip(n, t)]
dt
```

gets:

```
[('hru_id_nat', 'int32'),
 ('region', 'unicode8160'),
 ('POI_ID', 'int32'),
 ('hru_segment', 'int32')]
```

This throws an error when I try to use the dt specification to create the DF

```
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, dt)
```

doesn't help if I try these:

```
dt[1] = ('region', 'unicode')
dt[1] = ('region', 'str')
dt[1] = ('region', np.str)
```

I've also tried `convert_type()` (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197774/assign-pandas-dataframe-column-dtypes)) and `df['region'] = df['region'].astype(np.str)` (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180694/pandas-convert-column-of-unicodes-to-column-of-list-of-strings)), but neither seem to change the dtype reported by the DF.

Thanks much for any input.

Comment: Clarification question: are you just confused that the datatype reported by the DataFrame is `object` and not `str`?  Because, **that's never going to happen.**  From the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/basics.html#dtypes): "The main types stored in pandas objects are float, int, bool, datetime64[ns], timedelta[ns], and object."  String data are always just stored as object datatype.  I'm guessing that the *real* problem is that you're having trouble getting your structured array back?

Comment: Also, if my guess is right, there are some fantastic examples of doing that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array-include-index).

Comment: @Ajean, you answered my main question: I can't get unicode/string columns in a dataframe. You are also right that I really need a structured array at the end of it all. I tried syntax like that in your suggestion, never quite getting it right (showed some samples above). I imagine there must be a reference page on the acceptable sytnax options. If anyone has that, I'm thinking this would get me through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand (which is entirely possible), I think you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271280) here .... the pandas DataFrame will never tell you that it has anything with a dtype of 'unicode'.  But your unicode data are perfectly safe stored as 'object'.  All string data are stored as an 'object' dtype<sup>1</sup>.

The problem of getting back the unicode dtype after converting from the DataFrame shouldn't be hard.  When I take your DataFrame and convert it using the `to_records` method, I get your string data ('region') as type `'O'`, which is what you  probably did:

```
>>> a = df.to_records()
>>> a
rec.array([(0L, 1, u'01', 7733855, 0), (1L, 2, u'01', 7733919, 1244),
       (2L, 3, u'01', 7732571, 1236), (3L, 4, u'01', 7732387, 1234),
       (4L, 5, u'01', 7733327, 1239), (5L, 6, u'01', 7733755, 1241),
       (6L, 7, u'01', 7732571, 1236), (7L, 8, u'01', 7733923, 0),
       (8L, 9, u'01', 7733327, 1239), (9L, 10, u'01', 7733755, 1241)], 
      dtype=[('index', '<i8'), ('hru_id_nat', '<i4'), ('region', 'O'), ('POI_ID', '<i4'), ('hru_segment', '<i4')])
```

But getting it back to unicode was as simple as re-using your original datatype object.

```
>>> dt = {'names':('hru_id_nat', 'region', 'POI_ID', 'hru_segment'),
      'formats':('<i4', '<U255', '<i4', '<i4')}
>>> b = a.astype(dt)
>>> b
rec.array([(1, u'01', 7733855, 0), (2, u'01', 7733919, 1244),
       (3, u'01', 7732571, 1236), (4, u'01', 7732387, 1234),
       (5, u'01', 7733327, 1239), (6, u'01', 7733755, 1241),
       (7, u'01', 7732571, 1236), (8, u'01', 7733923, 0),
       (9, u'01', 7733327, 1239), (10, u'01', 7733755, 1241)], 
      dtype=[(u'hru_id_nat', '<i4'), (u'region', '<U255'), (u'POI_ID', '<i4'), (u'hru_segment', '<i4')])
```

You might need to be wary of the index, so include an `index=False` keyword in the call to `to_records` if you don't want it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Prior to version 1.0.0, in which a [StringDType](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.StringDtype.html) was introduced. Use of the explicit type in modern versions of Pandas is encouraged - see [Text data types](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#text-types).

Answer (score 0):

check out the documentation [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/categorical.html)

here is the code I used to test it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arr = pd.DataFrame(data=[(1, u'01', 7733855, 0), (2, u'01', 7733919, 1244),
       (3, u'01', 7732571, 1236), (4, u'01', 7732387, 1234),
       (5, u'01', 7733327, 1239), (6, u'01', 7733755, 1241),
       (7, u'01', 7732571, 1236), (8, u'01', 7733923, 0),
       (9, u'01', 7733327, 1239), (10, u'01', 7733755, 1241)],) 

print arr, '\n', arr.dtypes
arr = arr.astype('string')
arr = arr.astype('int')
print arr.values, '\n', arr.dtypes
```

the output was

[image]

astype worked for me. my versions are python 2.7.6  pandas 0.13.1 and numpy 1.8.2

Comment: This is not quite what I was after. I want my unicode to be either unicode or string, and not object or a numerical type. Apologies if my question was not clear enough! I'll definitely look at that link you posted some more. I have not seen that yet--hadn't thought about categorical data at all in fact.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StringDType](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.StringDtype.html), which was introduced in pandas 1.0.0 in January 2020:

```
import pandas as pd
arr = ([(1, '01', 7733855, 0), (2, '01', 7733919, 1244),
       (3, '01', 7732571, 1236), (4, '01', 7732387, 1234),
       (5, '01', 7733327, 1239), (6, '01', 7733755, 1241),
       (7, '01', 7732571, 1236), (8, '01', 7733923, 0),
       (9, '01', 7733327, 1239), (10, '01', 7733755, 1241)])
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=["hru_id_nat", "region", "POI_ID", "hru_segment"])
df["region"] = df["region"].astype(pd.StringDtype())
```

Now we can use the `.str` accessor to do string operations:

```
In [11]: df["region"].str[1]
Out[11]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    1
8    1
9    1
Name: region, dtype: string
```

Note that as of pandas 1.5.2, the API for `StringDType()` is still marked as experimental and subject to change, so use at your own risk in production code.