# How to read UTF-8 files with Pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, utf-8

I have a UTF-8 file with twitter data and I am trying to read it into a Python data frame but I can only get an 'object' type instead of unicode strings:

```
# file 1459966468_324.csv
#1459966468_324.csv: UTF-8 Unicode English text
df = pd.read_csv('1459966468_324.csv', dtype={'text': unicode})
df.dtypes
text               object
Airline            object
name               object
retweet_count     float64
sentiment          object
tweet_location     object
dtype: object
```

What is the right way of reading and coercing UTF-8 data into unicode with Pandas?

This does not solve the problem:

```
df = pd.read_csv('1459966468_324.csv', encoding = 'utf8')
df.apply(lambda x: pd.lib.infer_dtype(x.values))
```

Text file is here:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/l1x/nlp/master/1459966468_324.csv

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20670901/2141635

Comment: Using `df.apply(lambda x: pd.lib.infer_dtype(x.values))` does show  types as unicode and   mixed, if you look at the link above you will see what is happening

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As the other poster mentioned, you might try:

```
df = pd.read_csv('1459966468_324.csv', encoding='utf8')
```

However this could still leave you looking at 'object' when you print the dtypes. To confirm they are utf8, try this line after reading the CSV:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.lib.infer_dtype(x.values))
```

Example output:

```
args            unicode
date         datetime64
host            unicode
kwargs          unicode
operation       unicode
```

Comment: It's because you have `nan` values. Try `df.dropna(subset=["text"], inplace=True)` first then Sam's suggestion will convert the text column to unicode in the file you provided.

Comment: Can someone explain why you even need to provide the `encoding` argument for pandas? Looking at the docs, it says the field is optional, so I assume it would default to the python3 default of utf8 but it doesn't seem like that's true https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Perhaps it's a recent update---I had to add `._libs`. So, `df.apply(lambda x: pd._libs.lib.infer_dtype(x.values))`

Answer (score 5):

Use the `encoding` keyword with the appropriate parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv('1459966468_324.csv', encoding='utf8')
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas stores strings in `object`s. In python 3, all string are in unicode by default. So if you use python 3, your data is already in unicode (don't be mislead by type `object`).

If you have python 2, then use `df = pd.read_csv('your_file', encoding = 'utf8')`. Then try for example `pd.lib.infer_dtype(df.iloc[0,0])` (I guess the first col consists of strings.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the location of this function has moved. This worked for me on 1.0.1:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.api.types.infer_dtype(x.values))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the appropriate parameter for the encoding keyword is:

```
df = pd.read_csv('1459966468_324.csv', encoding='latin1')
```