# Pandas DataFrame cuts off when importing a text file when engine=python

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose you have a text file with the following information:
[Link to "test.txt" file on scribd.com](https://www.scribd.com/document/341329341/Test)

I want to upload the text file onto Pandas. Here's the code that I'm using to upload it:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_table("test.txt",sep="þ",engine='python')
df1.drop(df1.columns[[0,2,4,6]],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

When I view what's in df1, I get the following:

```
    A        B                                          C
0   1        How are you doing? I am fine today         NaN
```

When I then type

```
df1["B"][0]
```

... I get

```
'How are you\x06 doing? I am fi\x06ne to\x1bday'
```

However, I then manually converted the .txt file's delimiters from thorn-pilcrow-thorn to pipe. [Link to "test2.txt" file on scribd.com](https://www.scribd.com/document/341329872/test2)
I then used the following code:

```
df2 = pd.read_table("test2.txt",sep="|")
```

That one came out fine, i.e.,

```
    A        B                                              C
0   1        How are you doing? I am fine today my fri...   3
```

When I then type

```
df2["B"][0]
```

... I get

```
'How are you\x06 doing? I am fi\x06ne to\x1bday\x1a my\x11 friend\x12.'
```

df2 is what I want because I don't lose column C's value, but I don't want to be doing the manual conversion of  thorn-pilcrow-thorn to pipe and removing the first and last thorns of each line.
What's the most effective way of getting df2 if you receive "test.txt"? If possible, I would prefer to get the following for cell B0:

```
'How are you doing? I am fine today my friend.'
```

Comment: why do it manually? you can easily do that in python - read the file, convert it, then send it into pandas in a StringIO. unless the data is very large....

Comment: Understood. Isn't there an engine other than "python" that can read the thorn sign as a separator value? Omitting the engine causes pandas to raise an error.

Comment: I think this is because the thorn is not a standard ASCII text - e.g. (in python 2.7) `"þ"` = `'\xc3\xbe'`, but `u"þ"` = `u'\xfe'`. is this UTF-8? maybe follow here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462852/how-to-read-utf-8-files-with-pandas