# Reading multilingual files in Python 3.9

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ascii, multilingual

I have encountered a bit of a challenge when working with a CSV file that contains about 5 languages (English, French, Spanish, German, Italian, Swedish). The aim is to merge values from OneCol (a concatenated column in my df) to different dictionaries. Another condition is to merge based on the country column (e.g. French will be checked with the FR dictionary). I am having trouble with reading the file, everything I have tried ended but in a total failure, I feel a bit exhausted. The dictionaries also contain special chars/dictionaries, in this case, are data frame which I transformed them into lists.
The error I am getting is: `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 89: ordinal not in range.`
My code looks something like this:

```
df['ResultG'] = np.where(df["Country"].isin(['1','2','12']), f['OneCol'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(list(set(x.split()) & set(words.words())))), np.where(df["Country"]=='3', df['OneCol'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(list(set(x.split()) & set(list_fr)))), "Other"))
```

I tried everything from setting the file to utf-8 to actually changing the file in Notepad++. Any ideas or suggestions are welcomed. Thank you

Comment: 0xe4 is a UTF-8 continuation byte, but it's treated as an ascii encoded string there. Have you tried setting `encoding="utf-8"` in read_csv (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462852/how-to-read-utf-8-files-with-pandas)?

Comment: Thanks, I solved this by going into notepad++ and converted the file from ANSI to UTF-8. Also, I think that installing all the packages from NLTK messed up my syntax. All sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem: my file had an ANSI format. I used Notepad++ to convert it to UTF-8. In Notepad++ go to Encoding and select convert to UTF-8. Then add this little piece of code to your data frame:

```
df=pd.read_csv(r'file path.txt', encoding='utf-8')
```

My other problem was because I tried many 'solutions' something went wrong, I couldn't use Python, not even for a text in English. I had to reinstall everything.

Hope my answer will help you.