# Writing DataFrame to encoded JSON Newline Delimited

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Python 2.7, I have a Pandas Dataframe with several unicode columns, integer columns, etc. I need to be able to write it encoded utf-8 to JSON Newline Delimited file.

I tried this, but it only works in Python 3, not Python 2.7.

```
with io.open('myjson.json','w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(df.to_json(orient="records", lines=True, force_ascii=False))
```

This is my attempt's result, but as you can see it's not encoded utf-8.

```
{"account_id":"support","case_id":7697,"message":"\u0633\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0639","created_at":1536606086392,"agent":"108915"} 
{"account_id":"support","case_id":7697924,"message":"\u0647\u0627\u064a","created_at":1536601516354,"agent":"108915"}
```

I think it has something to do with [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15132#issuecomment-272749582). But I'm not sure.

Other research I've done shows that if I put this in my code it works. But I also read that this isn't recommended.

```
import sys
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit - I missed the 2.7 part - I usually use 3.5 or higher. In any case, w/ python 2.7, I was able to convert the unicode string to utf-8 using codecs:

```
import codecs 
codecs.unicode_escape_decode(a['message'])[0].encode("utf-8") 
'\xd8\xb3\xd8\xa8 \xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x84\xd9\x87\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x84\xd9\x87 \xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb9'
```

Old answer -

It looks like pandas .to_json() has a default setting of ensure_ascii=True, which converts non ascii to Unicode.

From docs:

```
to_json(path_or_buf=None, orient=None, date_format=None, double_precision=10, force_ascii=True, date_unit='ms', default_handler=None, lines=False, compression=None, index=True)
```

Try setting it to False:

```
df.to_json(force_ascii=False)
'{"agent":{"0":"108915"},"created_at":{"0":1536606086392},"message":{"0":"سب اللهالله الع"}}'
```

Edit - Forgot you were looking for newline delimited,

```
>>> df.to_json(force_ascii=False, orient="records")
[{"agent":"108915","created_at":1536606086392,"message":"سب اللهالله الع"}]
```

Comment: Can't get this to work for me in Python 2.7 (this is what I need). I know this works in Python 3 though.

Comment: Did you see this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670370/pandas-and-unicode